# Select com inner join com CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Estou com um probleminha a algum tempo referente a um projeto que estou desenvolvendo em **cakephp**, minha *view* não consegue ler um *select* com *inner join* da tabela.

Controller:

```
           public function initialize()
       {

           $posts = $this->Posts->find("all",array(
              "joins" => array(
                  array(
                    "table" => "users",
                    "alias" => "User",
                    "type" => "INNER",
                    "conditions" => array("Post.user_id = User.id "),
                    "fields" => array('Post.*', 'User.username')
                   )
               )
            )
         );
```

model;

```
      public function initialize(array $config) {
          $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
          $this->displayField('title');

         //join     
         $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

View

```php
<?= $post->username ?>
```

Código SQL

```sql
SELECT posts.*,
       users.username
FROM   posts
       INNER JOIN users
               ON ( posts.user_id = users.id )
```

Explicando melhor, essa consulta está buscando o "*username*" da tabela A para a tabela B, sendo que essa tabela B minha *view* consegue fazer a leitura normalmente. Com esse *select* meu banco traz a consulta exatamente que eu preciso, mas minha *view* não mostra o resultado e retorna nulo. Ou diz se eu tentar fazer a view assim:     $post->users->username, retorna um erro que não encontra o objeto *users*.

Comment: Como você está passando os dados para a view?

Comment: <?= $post->username ?> é minha view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém precise da resolução, consegue faze-la adicionando esse código no PostsController.

```
           public function index()
               {   
           $posts = $this->Posts->find('all', [
              'conditions' => ['Posts.online !=' => -1]])->order(['Posts.publication' => 'DESC'])->contain(['Users']);
           $this->set(compact(['posts']));
               }
```

Model

```
        public function initialize(array $config) {
            //funcao para trazer username do inner join
            $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
            $this->displayField('title');
            $this->belongsTo('Users', [
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'joinType' => 'INNER',
            ]);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Com `JOIN's` o CakePHP coloca os valores dentro dos seus respectivos objetos.

Provavelmente o seu `username` está dentro do objecto `User`:

```
$post->user->username
```

Dê um `pr()` no seu objeto `$post` para que ele exiba todos os atributos.

Em vez de fazer `sql` puro, você poderia usar as propriedades `belongsTo()`, `hasMany()` e `hasOne()` do CakePHP.

---

Você precisa fazer a consulta no seu controller e setar a variável para que ela exista em sua view.

Controller

```
$posts = $this->loadModel('Posts');
$all = $posts->find('all');

$this->set('posts', $all);
```

Model Posts - Usando o [`belongsTo()`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

```
class PostsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Users');
    }

}
```

Caso você não tenha criado as suas models, verifique esse [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/orm.html)

Comment: Sim Jeferson, esta dentro do obj User. Pode me dar um exemplo de como usar o pr() ?

Comment: a função `pr()` do cake, nada mais é que um `<pre>print_r()</pre>`, você pode usar da seguinte forma: `pr($post)`, se a minha resposta estiver correta, marque ela para que possa ajudar outras pessoas que tenha o mesmo problema.

Comment: Usando dessa forma, a coluna "username" esta retornando vários arrays, como por exemplo: [_accessible:protected] => Array e [_properties:protected] => Array

Comment: Usando o `pr()` ele vai exibir tudo do objeto, porém chamando `$post->user->username` ele te retorna somente o valor

Comment: me retorna o erro "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: tenta dessa forma `$post->User->username`

Comment: Mesmo erro, não preciso setar nada no controller?

Comment: Posta o código que esta no método da sua controller

Comment: Postei como resposta a minha pergunta.

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloque nela, no seu código da controller você não faz nenhuma consulta referente à posts, somente a parte do `AuthComponent`

Comment: Editei. Como eu poderia fazer essa consulta?

Comment: Editei minha respostas, pelo que entendi você não esta utilizando as models para fazer a consulta e esta tentando chamar posts na view sem setar

Comment: fiz as inclusões conforme você orientou, mas na view, minha coluna "username" continua retornando NULL, se eu fizer, por exemplo $post->user_id (que é uma coluna criada na tabela "post"), puxa certinho os Id, mas se eu fizer $post->username (username que é uma coluna da tabela Users) considerando o inner join que eu fiz, retorna null.

Comment: Porque o `usename` esta dentro do objeto User (ou user), tenta `$post->user->username` ou `$post->User->username`

Comment: Editei a pergunta com algumas alterações